# normal map from hand painted texture?

Tags: texture-painting, normals, normal-map

How are normal maps like this made from hand painted textures? I know you can convert these textures in other software like photoshop or gimp but the results come out very different than the one pictured below in my experience. I've found that some people will go in and hand paint over the normal map to fix compression artifacts and antialiasing. But what is a good technique to get similar results?   [image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure to understand, to get a normal map you either need to bake the 3D relief of an object, or convert an image to a normal map with softwares like CrazyBump or online converter like NormalMap-Online

Comment: I know you can convert the maps,  but dont they need to be greyscale images to work properly to convert to a normal map?

Comment: I think the software will use the values to convert, so I don't think it needs to be b&w but you need to test